# Issue with Hailstone sequence program C++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm working on a program and for the most part I have it down. The only issue I'm facing is that my `largest()` function (which is attempting to use a scan algorithm) is returning completely ridiculous values when trying to find the largest integer in a given hailstone sequence of n. It seems that for the first few values I test it comes out fine they're small like 1 or 2 but if i enter 3 or above I'll get something like 1153324768, which isn't the answer at all. Would anyone be able to steer me in the right direction for fixing this error? I've listed my code below

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


// Next(n) returns the number that follows n in a hailstone sequence.
// For example, next(7) = 22 and next(8) = 4.
//
// Next requires n > 1, since there is no number that follows 1.

int Next(int n)
{
    int remainder;
    remainder = n % 2;
    if (n>1)
    {
        if(remainder == 0)
        {
            return n/2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 3 * n + 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return n;
    }
}

// The function writeHailstoneSequence(n) will take the parameter n
// and write the entire hailstone sequence starting from n, all in one     line.

void writeHailstoneSequence(int n)
{
    printf("The hailstone sequence starting with %d is: %d ", n, n);
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n = Next(n);
        printf("%d ", n);
    }
}  

// The function lengthHailstone(n) will take the parameter n and return     the
// the length of the hailstone sequence starting at n.

int lengthHailstone(int n)
{
    int length = 1;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n = Next(n);
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

//The function largest(n) will take one parameter, integer n, and return the largest value.

int largest(int n)
{
    int A[] = {};
    int big = A[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    { 
        big = max(big, A[i]);
    }
    return big;
}

// The function longest(n) will return the longest hailstone sequence starting witht a number from 1 to n.

int longest(int n)
{
    int lon = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        lon = lengthHailstone(n);
    }
    return lon;
}

// The function largestHailstone(n) returns the largest value that occurs in a hailstone sequence that starts
// with a number from 1 to n.
int biggestHailstone(int n)
{
    int biggest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        biggest = largest(n);
    }
    return biggest;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("What number shall I start with?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    writeHailstoneSequence(n);
    printf("\nThe length of the sequence is: %d\n", lengthHailstone(n));
    printf("The largest number in the sequence is %d\n", largest(n));
    printf("The longest hailstone sequence starting with a number up to %d has a length %d\n", n, longest(n));
    printf("The longest hailstone sequence starting with a number up to %d begins with %d", n, biggestHailstone(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Would anyone be able to steer me in the right direction for fixing this error?"_ NP, sure. Use your debugger step through your code line by line, and watch how and where your variable values are changing.

Comment: `int A[] = {};` - this line is wrong. I'm not exactly sure, but it probably creates an array of 0 elements (or is undefined behaviour). What are you trying to achieve there? Where exactly are trying to retrieve numbers from? You don't pass anything except one int to this function. Maybe you wanted to calculate the elements of the series and find running maximum of that?

Comment: Code does not compile.  from g++:   " int A[] = {}; // error: zero-size array ‘A’  "  Also, remember that C++ does not support:  " error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘A’ [-Werror=vla] "  Consider vector.

Comment: I think you need to put the hailstone values into the array "A[]".  The array A in function largest(int n)  is empty when you scan it.  Clearly you did not pass any values to put into it.

Answer (score 0):

> The only issue I'm facing is that my largest() function (which is
>   attempting to use a scan algorithm) is returning completely ridiculous
>   values when trying to find the largest integer in a given hailstone
>   sequence of n...  Would anyone be able to steer me in the right direction for 
>   fixing this error?

Primary investigation direction:

You failed to capture the hailstone sequence into your array A.